# Is there a way to add extra colors in-game?

Tags: one-must-fall-2097

Is there a way to use other colors like the robots that are in the tournament?

There's no green color to set in my robot, perhaps there's a way to trick the savefile into that, enable it through the cycling panel or something?

Comment: Oh man, it's been a long time since I've played that game. But don't they already have a full set of standard colors (including green)?

Comment: They don't. All the characters in the tournaments do not use eligible colors, except the ones that are also in single player.